# How to implement MQTT Broker side Authorization?

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

I have an MQTT broker where devices are connecting to it and publishing data to the broker and I have a nodejs program that helps clients, subscribe to the topic, and receive the data they are publishing through their device.

Now my use case is to provide each client with a unique token which they have to send while connecting the MQTT broker in order to start publishing the data. And I want to validate that client token using an API and then establish a connection between the client and MQTT Broker.

I have searched for my use case but I have not found any help.

Answer (score 2):

Mosquitto has an authorisation plugin API that will let you build your authentication scheme.

The doc for the API is [here](https://mosquitto.org/api/files2/mosquitto_plugin-h.html)

You can also search GitHub for existing auth plugins e.g. https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug (this plugin is no longer being developed but there are active forks)

Comment: There'a a new auth plugin someone wrote in Go. It's working well for me though generating encrypted passwords can be a bit fussy (which I found for the old one, too): https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth

Comment: Are there any examples showing how to implement it?

Comment: I  already provided a link to the example on github...

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to give up using Mosquitto, you can instead use the [aedes](https://github.com/moscajs/aedes) node.js library that lets you easily set up an mqtt broker.

There you can implement any auth logic you want, by using the `handler.authenticate`, `handler.authorizePublish` and `handler.authorizeSubscribe`. No need to rely on a plugin.